# Stuck on finding a largest/greatest number in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, max

I have been trying to get a whole array to populate the greatest number within it and I am stumbling. 
In my HTML code, I have a number input box where a user can enter it and an alert populate once a user clicks on the "button":

```
 <label for="numbers">Enter numbers seperated by a space.</label><input type="text" size="20" id="numbers">

 <div id="greatestbutton" class="button">Click here to get the Greatest Number!</div>

 <div>The greatest number is in the alert box.<span id="numbers"></span></div>
```

In my JS Code, I can get it to recognize the parseFloat, only if the non digit is the first character in the input box, for example "i782" will populate NaN in the alert box, but "7i82", will only populate a 7 in the alert box. 
Furthermore, I am unable to get it to go past the first space " ". I am thoroughly stumped and I am also confused that if I put the alert to the var (greatest), it just comes back as 0, yet when I put in alert(array) I at least get something that I hve entered. I know I am missing a step somewhere, but I totally lost. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated!!! Thanks!!.

```
   var button = document.getElementById("greatestbutton");
     button.onclick = function greaterNumber() {
   var array = parseFloat(document.getElementById('numbers').value);
   var greatest = 0;
      for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++){

      if (array[i] > greatest){ 

    var greatest = Math.max(array[i])};
  }
  alert(array);
  }
```

Comment: I'm missing something. Do you want to parse the contents of the `numbers` value as an _array_ of numbers? `parseFloat` doesn't do anything like that. Also, it's a little weird to declare `var greatest` twice. Just declare it once and use it without the `var` declaration after that.

Comment: Correct, I want to go through the numbers as an array. I want to ensure that they are valid numbers, not letters or anything. That is why I was using parseFloat. So if I left the last var greatest at just greatest, would that help the calcs? I actually just tried it in my fiddle and it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple things going wrong here.

For starters, what you want to do is find each valid textual representation of a number in the input box.  This is a bit trickier than it sounds - do you want to support negative numbers?  Decimal places?

Enter the Regular Expression, one of the most useful inventions in the history of programming.  Using a regular expression one can, without too much difficulty, extract all the valid numeric sequences from strings like `abc-.02dflaxoe042xne+3.14-5` ( `-0.2`, `042`, `+3.14`, and `-5`, that is - all of which can be parsed by `parseFloat` *individually*.

This regex does the trick:

```
/[-+]?(\d+(\.\d+)?|\.\d+)/g
```

It matches an optional leading `-` or `+` ( `[-+]?` ), followed by *either*

- `\d+(\.\d+)?`: one or more decimal number 0-9 ( `\d` ) followed optionally by a decimal point ( `\.` )and one or more decimal numbers

*or*

- a decimal point `\.` followed by one or more decimal numbers

The first case matches +3.2, -31, -0.0001, 51, or 42 - the second matches .2, -.1, or +.31.  That second case is a bit unusual (no decimal numbers before the decimal point ) but since `parseFloat` could read them I added them in.

Some might argue that there's a simpler way to write this - I do wish I could combine the either/or, but I couldn't figure out a better regex that made sure that at least one numeric character was supplied.  Edits welcome.

The parsing trick, trick, as you were approaching, is to parse out all the numeric substrings first, then parse each into a floating point number and compare.  You had some of the right ideas, but there were still some things missing.

`Math.max()` takes one or more numeric arguments, but can't take an array, unfortunately.  It would make a lot of sense if it could, but it can't.  I didn't try to find a way around this, though there might be one, because I had to parse each of the numeric strings anyway, I just took `max()` out completely and used the `>` operator instead.

A general programming point now: when you're looking for the greatest, don't make assumptions like starting the search at 0.  In your example, if no numbers are supplied, or all negative numbers, then the greatest number is your starting point of `0` - which the user may not even have inputted.  I initialized my `greatest` to `undefined` and then handled that case below.

A bit of further help:

```
var button = document.getElementById("greatestbutton");
button.onclick = function greaterNumber() {
```

is a long way of using a variable to say

```
document.getElementById("greatestbutton").onclick = function greaterNumber() {
```

You'll notice that you have both the output `<span>` and the `<input>` field ( which should end with `/>`, by the way) with an `id` of `numbers` - you can't refer to two elements with the same ID of course.

Finally, a semantic point ( :-) ): As a believer in the semantic principles of markup, I'll ask you to avoid all-too-common anti-patterns such as `<div id="greatestbutton" class="button">`.  There is already a `<button>` tag, and users will be told it's a button even if they're on a braille terminal or other such devices - a `<div class='button'>` loses this semantic meaning regardless of how pretty you make it with CSS.  For the same reason, I replaced your `<span>` with a `<kbd>` tag ( for "typed input").

Here's what I came up with:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
greaterNumber = function () {
    var array = document.getElementById('numbers').value.match(/[-+]?(\d+(\.\d+)?|\.\d+)/g)
    alert(array)
    if (!array || array.length <= 0) return; // no numbers at all!
    var greatest = undefined
    if (array.type == 'number') // only one number
    array = [array] // convert to array for simplicity
    for (var i in array) {
        array[i] = parseFloat(array[i])
        if (greatest == undefined || array[i] > greatest) greatest = array[i]
    }
    document.getElementById('greatest').innerHTML = greatest;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <p>
    <label for="numbers">Enter numbers seperated by a space:</label>
    <input type="text" size="20" id="numbers" />
</p>
<p>
    <button id="greatestbutton" onclick="greaterNumber()">Click here to get the Greatest Number!</button>
</p>
<div>The greatest number is in the alert box: <kbd id="greatest">?</kbd>
</div>
</html>
```

See a working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/7JN74/10/

Comment: Ok, I am still trying to play with it on my end to fully understand and I am lost. Sorry, js newbie. If I dont need to worry about decimels and negatives, do i need this?                             value.match(/[-+]?(\d+(\.\d+)?|\.\d+)/g)
    alert(array)

Comment: Ok, so i tried a different way and now I am getting undefined.        var button = document.getElementById("greatestbutton");
button.onclick = function greaterNumber() {
var myArray = new Array(parseFloat(document.getElementById('numbers').value));
    var greatest = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {

        if (myArray[i] > greatest) {

            var myGreatest =(myArray[i])
        };
    }
    alert(myGreatest);
}           Here is my fiddle for it:http://jsfiddle.net/jminery/VRTax/2/